# Facing Thumbprint mismatch error with .pfx certificate in azure devops pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have added a .pfx certificate in my VS and able to build successfully but when I run a pipeline It throwing Thumb print mismatch error.

1. I have removed and re added the certificate
2. Removed manifest property group and tried..Its throwing different error like "Manifest sign checkbox is unchecked"

Please find the error below:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(162,9):
>   Error : Cannot find the certificate that matches the project system
>   thumbprint.  To sign the application and deployment manifests, open
>   the Project Designer, click the Signing page tab, select an existing
>   certificate, and try again. Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code
>   '1'.

Comment: Please add the <MainfestKeyFile> back into your csproj file. It is a VSTO project, and in your script, somewhere need this certification to sign. If you uncheck, it will tell you that currently script need to get value from this argument, but you don’t have. So I report the error to you.

Comment: @Merlin...Powershell script u suggested was throwing below errors:-
Cannot find an overload for "Import" and the argument count: "3".
At D:\a\_temp\a7665445-507c-4061-91eb-84b098083297.ps1:10 char:1
+ $cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: did you forget use **Download secure file** task to download the `pfx` file into your repos? This error is haven't found the `pfx` file from the location `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\{path}\{certfile}.pfx`.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT didn't forget....it's there in our pipeline.

Comment: @user11708158 Did you get this working?